# Sort and sum up gridview column in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I just wanna ask some help, maybe someone here can help me. I'll gonna go straight to my query.

So I have a gridview that displays `column1` and `column2`.

In column1 contains random numbers like 1-100 every row,

also in column2 that only contains 1 and 0(like true or false).

It looks like this in gridview,

```
column1 | column2 |

15       |   1      |       

19       |   1      |       

26       |   0      |       

75       |   1      |
```

so on and so forth. What I wanna do is to get the total value of column2 that has a value of 15 to 19 in column1(by bracket) and to display the total value in textbox1.

In this example, (15-19, by bracket) of column1 has a total value of 2 in column2. Sample of bracket I'm using is like this (15-19, 20-24, 25-29, so on and so forth.).

```
    Dim rows() As DataRow = datatable.Select("column1 = '15'")
    Dim total As Double = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.RowCount - 1
        total += GridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "column2")
    Next
    TextEdit1.Text = total
```

The code above ends up adding all the value of column 2.

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DataTable.Compute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=netcore-3.1) method can perform both filtering and apply an aggregate function such as summing a column.

Assuming that both column1 and column2 contain integer values (your code is using the Double type for summing column2, the data appears to be integer type), your code could be reduced to a single statement for given range of column1.

```
TextEdit1.Text = datatable.Compute("Sum(column2)", "column1 >= 15 AND column1 <= 19").ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there - your `datatable.Select("column1 = '15'")` query will only return rows where the value is exactly `"15"` (either only string values or it does implicit conversion to numbers, I forget, this is ancient and obsolete API btw) - but your code doesn't use the `rows` variable at all.

I think this would work:

[See this page for a reference for the `DataTable.Select(String)` syntax, as it's its own thing that's separate from VB.NET/C# or even SQL](https://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/).

```
    Dim rows() As DataRow = datatable.Select("column1 >= 15 AND colum1 <= 19")

    Dim total As Double = 0

    For Each row As DataRow in rows
        total += CDbl( row("colum2") )
    Next

    TextEdit1.Text = total.ToString("N0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach with additional type checking help.

```
Dim total As Integer= datatable.AsEnumerable().
    Where(Function(row) row.Field<Integer>("column1") >= 15).
    Where(Function(row) row.Field<Integer>("column1") <= 19).
    Select(Function(row) row.Field<Integer>("column2")).
    Sum()

TextEdit1.Text = total.ToString()
```